# Blank command prompt in Windows using Octave

Tags: windows-10, octave

I'm using Octave 3.6.4 on Windows 10. All appears to be working ok, *except* there's no command prompt.

I know that you can [Customize the prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Customizing-the-Prompt.html) using `PS1`, but that still leaves it blank.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a few unsuccessful searches, a search for '[octave windows show prompt](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=octave+windows+show+prompt&t=ffab&ia=web)', turned up this [YouTube video on a Windows 10/8 crash fix](https://youtu.be/CrDgSJmgfLA?t=27s) that suggests starting Octave with the following command:

```
C:\> octave -i --line-editing
```

That indeed gives me the following command prompt:

```
octave:1>
```

For more information this is the help info on those options:

```
--interactive, -i       Force interactive behavior.
--line-editing          Force readline use for command-line editing.
```